# Unable to substitute Jenkins build number variable in pipeline script

Tags: variables, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I have a pipeline in which I am trying to pass the Build Number.

When I print the Build Number its prints fine however, I am having issues passing it to the a shell ansible command inside a stage.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'Prod_Slave' }
    stages {

        stage('Ansible stuff') {
            parallel {
                stage('APP') {

            steps {
                echo "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                         println "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                         sh 'ansible-playbook $ansible_playbook/site.yml -e Latest_Build_Number4=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'
                    }
                }

}
}

}
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] 
echo (hide) 
16 [Pipeline] 
echo 16 [Pipeline] 
echo 16

 /script.sh: line 1: Latest_Build_Number4=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}: bad
 substitution
```

When i change to:

```
sh 'ansible-playbook $ansible_playbook/site.yml -e Latest_Build_Number4="${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"'
```

Output:

```
 @2@tmp/durable-5ed077ca/script.sh: line 1: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}: bad
 substitution
```

Finally tried this:

```
sh 'ansible-playbook $ansible_playbook/site.yml -e Latest_Build_Number4="$env.BUILD_NUMBER"'
```

Output:

```
  -e Latest_Build_Number4=.BUILD_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes won't allow substitution. Try double quotes, escaping the dollar sign:

```
sh "ansible-playbook \$ansible_playbook/site.yml -e Latest_Build_Number4=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

Comment: Thanks works!! However curious to know if variables could be substituted under single quotes?

Comment: No, only inside double `" ... "` or triple `""" ... """`. The latter is a good choice when you need to mix the quotes.